# SendKeys lead to "Leav page" alert

Tags: java, xml, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

HTML

```
<input type="text" value="" style="margin-left: 0px" autocomplete="off" 
name="data[param_p][1]" class="paramP">
```

Java Selenium code

```
action.sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='data[param_p][1]']")), 
"250000").build().perform();
```

Why this code leads to alert and how to send keys properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use `actions` for this? `sendKeys` can be used directly to set the values in an input field.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='data[param_p][1]']")).sendKeys("250000");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`sendKeys()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-) directly on [`WebElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) after finding `input` element using `By.Name`. Avoid using `By.xpath`, if you can easily find the element by it's name because locating element using `xpath` is slower as compare to the other locator. Try as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.name("data[param_p][1]")).sendKeys("250000");
```

Hope it helps...:)